# htaccess - language switch by putting language in page url works on localhost, not on prod

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to implement a language switch. I've been doing a lot of research and most of it is fully implemented. The goal is to make a properly working language switch in the URL:

How my normal page url looks:

> example.com/mypage

What I want:

> example.com/nl/mypage

I've got this to **work perfectly on localhost**. But after submitting the changes to the production website, it broke and sends me to a 404 page.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Language Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -d
RewriteRule ^(it|nl)/(.*[^/])$ /$1/$2/ [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(it|nl)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite page path to parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What could be the cause of this? How can I get it to work on production?

If there's any other solution that works with the "Rewrite page path to parameter" rewrite, please do let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing what I have in the question with the following rule rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2 [L]
```